# NaN produced for prediction Intervals with neural networks in R

Tags: r, neural-network, regression, prediction

I want to find prediction intervals of predictions computed via neural networks (package `nnet`). Specifically, I am using `nnetpredInt` package of `R` to compute such intervals. So, the code is

```
library(nnet)
library(nnetpredint)
xtrain <- tdata[,!colnames(tdata) %in% "power"]
ytrain <- tdata$power
train_model <- nnet(x = xtrain, y= ytrain,linout=FALSE, na.action = na.exclude, trace=FALSE,size=4)
yFit = train_model$fitted.values
pred_intervals <- nnetPredInt(train_model, xTrain = xtrain, yTrain = ytrain, newData = dframe)
```

This generates following Warnings:

```
Warning messages:
1: In sqrt(varEst) : NaNs produced
2: In qt(alpha/2, df = (nObs - nPara)) : NaNs produced
```

Why does this result in `NaN`?
`dput()` of the training and testing data is:

```
tdata = structure(list(power = c(1578.209605, 186.636575166667, 1062.07912666667, 
1031.481235, 1584.38902166667, 276.973836666667, 401.620463333333, 
1622.50827666667, 273.825153333333, 1511.37474333333, 291.460865, 
215.138178333333, 247.509348333333, 1140.21383833333, 1680.63441666667, 
1742.44168333333, 592.162706166667, 1610.7307, 615.857495, 1664.13551, 
464.973065, 1956.2482, 1767.94469333333, 1869.02678333333, 1806.731, 
1746.3731, 549.216605, 1425.42390166667, 1900.32575, 1766.18103333333
), temperature = c(28, 28, 27, 31, 32, 32, 30.5, 33, 33, 30, 
32, 24, 30, 26, 28, 32, 34, 25, 32, 33, 35, 36, 36, 37, 35, 33, 
35, 33, 35, 32), prevday1 = c(252.675878333333, 1578.209605, 
186.636575166667, 1062.07912666667, 1031.481235, 1584.38902166667, 
276.973836666667, 401.620463333333, 1622.50827666667, 273.825153333333, 
1511.37474333333, 291.460865, 215.138178333333, 247.509348333333, 
1140.21383833333, 1680.63441666667, 1742.44168333333, 592.162706166667, 
1610.7307, 615.857495, 1664.13551, 464.973065, 1956.2482, 1767.94469333333, 
1869.02678333333, 1806.731, 1746.3731, 549.216605, 1425.42390166667, 
1900.32575), prevday2 = c(250.615931666667, 252.675878333333, 
1578.209605, 186.636575166667, 1062.07912666667, 1031.481235, 
1584.38902166667, 276.973836666667, 401.620463333333, 1622.50827666667, 
273.825153333333, 1511.37474333333, 291.460865, 215.138178333333, 
247.509348333333, 1140.21383833333, 1680.63441666667, 1742.44168333333, 
592.162706166667, 1610.7307, 615.857495, 1664.13551, 464.973065, 
1956.2482, 1767.94469333333, 1869.02678333333, 1806.731, 1746.3731, 
549.216605, 1425.42390166667), prev_instant1 = c(455.932271666667, 
367.837349666667, 1230.40137333333, 1080.74080166667, 1898.06056666667, 
326.103031666667, 302.770571666667, 1859.65283333333, 281.700161666667, 
1684.32288333333, 291.448878333333, 214.838578333333, 254.042623333333, 
1380.14074333333, 824.437228333333, 1660.46284666667, 268.004111666667, 
1715.02763333333, 1853.08503333333, 1821.31845, 1173.91945333333, 
1859.87353333333, 1887.67635, 1760.29563333333, 1876.05421666667, 
1743.10665, 366.382048333333, 1185.16379, 1713.98534666667, 1746.36006666667
), prev_instant2 = c(242.638122833333, 220.635857, 1784.77271666667, 
1195.45020333333, 590.114391666667, 310.141536666667, 1397.3184605, 
1747.44398333333, 260.10318, 1521.77355833333, 283.317726666667, 
206.678135, 231.428693833333, 235.600631666667, 232.455201666667, 
281.422625, 256.470893333333, 1613.82088333333, 1564.34841666667, 
1795.03498333333, 1551.64725666667, 1517.69289833333, 1596.66556166667, 
2767.82433333333, 2949.38005, 328.691775, 389.83789, 1805.71815333333, 
1153.97645666667, 1752.75968333333), prev_2_hour = c(313.393630708333, 
263.748829166667, 931.193606666667, 699.399163791667, 754.018962083334, 
272.22309625, 595.954508875, 1597.21487208333, 512.64361, 1236.42579666667, 
281.200373333334, 196.983981666666, 230.327737625, 525.483920416666, 
391.120302791667, 610.101280416667, 247.710625543785, 978.741044166665, 
979.658926666667, 1189.25306041667, 814.840889166667, 989.059700416665, 
1352.2367025, 1770.20417833333, 1847.11590666667, 843.191556416666, 
363.50806625, 904.924465041666, 841.746712500002, 1747.73452958333
)), .Names = c("power", "temperature", "prevday1", "prevday2", 
"prev_instant1", "prev_instant2", "prev_2_hour"), row.names = 3:32, class = "data.frame", na.action = structure(1:2, .Names = c("1", 
"2"), class = "omit"))
```

Testing data is:

```
dframe <- structure(list(temperature = 27, prevday1 = 1607.69296666667, 
                         prevday2 = 1766.18103333333, prev_instant1 = 1717.19306666667, 
                         prev_instant2 = 1577.168915, prev_2_hour = 1370.14983583333), .Names = c("temperature", 
                                                                                                  "prevday1", "prevday2", "prev_instant1", "prev_instant2", "prev_2_hour"
                         ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

Comment: I'm not an R user and skipped over your code. Maybe i'm wrong, but it looks, that your are using the raw data-values as input to your NN. You HAVE to normalize your inputs. Standard scaling is the keyword! This is very important for all SGD-based algorithms.

Comment: I normalized my data, but it still results in same `NaNs`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your neural network has many parameters, more than the number of training data.

If you look at the source code of the package nnetpredint, in the function calcSigmaEst (nnetGradient.R) you will see that nDegreeFree = nObs - nPara and in your case this value is negative.

If you set size=3 to create your model you will not get NaNs in the prediction intervals (irrespectively of whether you scale your data or not).